# Is it possible to pass a variable to jquery when it starts or every action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm super new to jquery and just stractching the surface of its awesomeness so sorry if this is a really basic question but I have a button on my site that once clicked posts some data to my server and I'm wondering how to provide jquery with data I want to be posted.  I have made jquery refreshless forms but they have required the user to enter something which I post but now I want to send some data that is not entered or available on the webpage.

On my site, I have a button to click on if you want to 'follow' a topic. If you follow a topic I need to send a topic_id and your user id to my server to start the process but I think putting this on my web page for jquery to capture would be confusing to users(if I can't pass variables I plan to do this approach but hide the fields).  The userid/topicid is avaiable to my template engine but I'm unsure how to pass the data over to the script.

Here's a example of my script
html:

```
<input type='button' value='Follow' id='btnFollow'>
```

follow.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnFollow').click(function() {
        //$("#btnFollow").prop('value', 'Following');
        if ($(this).val() == 'Follow') {
            $("#btnFollow").prop('value', 'Following')      
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'Following') {
            $("#btnFollow").prop('value', 'Follow') 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/follow_modification',
                async: true,
                data: {
                    fe1: "test"
                },
                complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
                    ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

How do I get info into the function from the html?  So far all my javascripts have been triggered by clicks and then take data from the page.. if I have a variable in my template called {{ user_id }} how can I pass that to the script so when a click triggers a action then it'll have the data it needs to post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<input type="button" value="Follow" id="btnFollow" data-topic="topicid" />`

```
$('#btnFollow').click(function() {
    var topic_id = $(this).attr('data-topic');
    alert(topic_id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type='button' value='Follow {{user-id}}' id='btnFollow' data-user="{{user-id}}">
```

on the html side, and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnFollow').click(function() {
    var following = $(this).attr("data-user");
    if ($(this).val() == 'Follow') {
        $("#btnFollow").prop('value', 'Following')      
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'Following') {
        $("#btnFollow").prop('value', 'Follow') 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/follow_modification',
            async: true,
            data: {
                fe1: following
            },
            complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
                ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
            }
        });
    }
})
});
```

on the js side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready((function ( data ) {
    // do some thing with somevalue
})( somevalue ));
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function (  ) {
    var data = $('someSelector').val()
    // do some thing with somevalue
});
```

or

```
var data = 'some value';
$(document).ready(function (  ) {
    // do some thing with somevalue
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  How do I get info into the function from the html?  So far all my javascripts have been triggered by clicks and then take data from the page.. if I have a variable in my template called {{ user_id }} how can I pass that to the script so when a click triggers a action then it'll have the data it needs to post?

Comment: write it into javascript part just treat it as a text file

Comment: sorry, I'm new and don't understand what you meant.  Are you saying put the script itself in my html and fill the data that way(right now its in a separate file?